# Azure storage data transfers and data out costs

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I hope someone could help us. Is there a way to move the storage account from West Europe to North Europe ? Are there any cost related to data transfers between two locations like this? If they would be in the same location, would there be no cost?

Also, we are looking into optimizing the Data Out costs, which are huge right now but we have no idea why. Is it possible to get some kind of a log or something so we can have a look ? It's standard Asp.Net Web App.

Thanks a lot.

Karel

Comment: Just curious, what would be the reason for moving the account to other region? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to move the storage account from West Europe to North Europe ?

As Renato Leite replied, you need to re-create the new storage account and copy data from your old storage account to the new one.

> Are there any cost related to data transfers between two locations like this? If they would be in the same location, would there be no cost?

For transferring data between two locations, you would pay for the **Bandwidth** and **Transactions**. While transferring data within the same location, the **Bandwidth** is free but the **Transactions** are not free. For more details, you could refer to [Understanding Windows Azure Storage Billing – Bandwidth, Transactions, and Capacity](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/07/08/understanding-windows-azure-storage-billing-bandwidth-transactions-and-capacity/).

Moreover, you could leverage [AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy) for copying data between storage accounts. Also, you could build an application and use [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.DataMovement) for achieving your purpose. For more details, you could refer to Data Movement Library documentation [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement).

> Also, we are looking into optimizing the Data Out costs, which are huge right now but we have no idea why. Is it possible to get some kind of a log or something so we can have a look ? It's standard Asp.Net Web App.

For storage account, you could configure metrics charts and logging for monitoring your storage account. For more details, you could refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitor-storage-account).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't move your storage account to a different region. You'll need to recreate the blobs, which will give you new keys. You cannot provide your own keys, so you cannot copy keys from your old storage account to your new storage account.

I hope that I have helped in some way.